# СМС шлюз для входящих смс

Tags: sms

Необходимо реализовать взаимодействие с GPS устройствами посредством обмена смс сообщениями. Механизм отправки смс в целом понятен, а вот как быть с получением смс. есть ли примеры подобных решений. Слышал о реализации через GSM модем, но вряд ли я его запихну в серверную. может есть более изящные решения.

Comment: Чем плох GSM модем в виде USB устройства размером с Flash накопитель? Гуглите ["API SMS шлюз"](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=API%20SMS%20%D1%88%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B7&lr=213)

Comment: в серверную его не поставить, тем более если севак у амазона

Comment: Тогда либо платить посредникам, либо пробрасывать модем удалённо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю что здесь подойдет двух сторонний смс шлюз. Логика такая. Вы отправляете команду на GPS устройство. (например через API из своей системы на сервер шлюза. потом шлюз прокидывает уже смс до устройства) Если устройство хочет ответить, то оно отправляет на тот же телефон смс-ответ; Смс-ответ уходит на сервер шлюза, по вебхуку уведомляет ваш сервер (или вы с периодичностью опрашиваете на наличие новых смс). и уже реагируете на эту смс согласно вашим бизнес задачам.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/440666)

Comment: спасибо. сделал изменения.